# Failed to save information to database

Tags: laravel

I'm quite new to laravel, created all that is needed but i can't edit or add new entries into the database. However i can successfully delete. what could be the problem not making the application write to the database?

This is my store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  //validate data
  $validation=$this->validate($request, [
    'username' => 'required|max:50',
    'role_id' => 'required|max:50',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:50',
  ]);

  $user = new User;
  $user->username = $request->username;
  $user->role_id = $request->role_id;
  $user->email = $request->email;
  $user->save();

  // redirect
  Session::flash('message', 'Successfully added the record!');
  Session::flash('alert-type', 'success');

  return Redirect::to('user');
}
```

Route

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::resource('user', 'UserController');

Route::resource('role', 'RoleController');
```

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: I've just included it above after editing

Comment: Are you getting any error??

Comment: yes, its a NotFoundException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Comment: Share your route code..  set route like this Route::post('/user/store', 'UserlController@store');

Comment: I added it but it is still giving me the same error

Comment: comment this line Route::resource('user', 'UserController'); and try

Comment: i did that too but it still brings the same error...

Comment: How to submit this form.. Share html code also

Comment: @O'Byron: I placed basic example link into my answer check it.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `store` method with below given and let me know which message will print?

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  //validate data
  $validation=$this->validate($request, [
    'username' => 'required|max:50',
    'role_id' => 'required|max:50',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:50',
  ]);

  $user = new User;
  $user->username = $request->username;
  $user->role_id = $request->role_id;
  $user->email = $request->email;
  $user->save();

    //Success redirect
  if($user){
    Session::flash('message', 'Successfully added the record!');
    Session::flash('alert-type', 'success');
  }
  //Failed redirect
  else {
    Session::flash('message', 'Something went wrong!');
    Session::flash('alert-type', 'success');
  }

  return Redirect::to('user');
}
```

For get the ride of [basic CRUD with laravel example](http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/crud-create-read-update-delete-example-in-laravel-52-from-scratchexample.html).

Comment: when i try editing, it shows that it is loading but it does not redirect to another page. and when i try adding a user, it brings the "NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161" error

Comment: Your route is not properly set. Try `Route::post('/user/store', 'UserlController@store');` into `Route` and use this action for store data.

Comment: DataTables warning: table id=role - Requested unknown parameter '3' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Comment: that is the error i am now seeing when i try to edit

Answer (score 1):

User Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  //validate data
  $validation=$this->validate($request, [
    'username' => 'required|max:50',
    'role_id' => 'required|max:50',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:50',
  ]);

  $user = new User;
  $user->username = $request->username;
  $user->role_id = $request->role_id;
  $user->email = $request->email;
  $user->save();

  // redirect
  Session::flash('message', 'Successfully added the record!');
  Session::flash('alert-type', 'success');

  return Redirect::to('user');
}
```

Your routes

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::post('/user/store', 'UserController@store');
```

Your form

```
<form id="form-add-user" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/user/store') }}">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> 
...
</form>
```